# Redirection from https:// domain alias to subfolder on a secured https://

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, subdomain, subdirectory

I now have a https:// secure server.

But now the redirection does n’t work anymore.
The redirection e.g. from `agenda.harmonicahoek.nl => https://www.harmonicahoek.nl/service/agenda/`

This what is now in the .htacces:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.harmonicahoek.nl/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} agenda.harmonicahoek.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.harmonicahoek.nl/service/agenda/ [r=301,NC]
```

But this does not work.
How will it work?

Comment: What exactly is the unintended behavior you're experiencing? A little more to go on than "this doesn't work".

Comment: If fact the redirection does n’t work, but I goes to my homepage. https://www.harmonicahoek.nl